# Flask-WTForms QuerySelectField - not showing selected option on edit

Tags: flask-wtforms

I current have a User Model that is Updated with a user_role in the database. this update is done using WTForms and SqlAlchemy using the QuerySelectField. I can update the database and everything is working fine. However when I want to update the role of a user and i edit that user the QuerySelectField from the form does not show the current value of the user_role for the in the database, it shows the first option in the database of user_roles.

**UserForm used for adding a user_role to a user**

```
class UserForm(FlaskForm):

    user_role_opts = QuerySelectField(query_factory=lambda: UserRole.query,
                                  get_pk=lambda x: x.id, get_label="role_name")
    submit = SubmitField()
```

**Models**

```
class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    clients = db.relationship('Client',
                            secondary=user_clients,
                            back_populates='users')
    user_role_id_user = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_role.id'))

class UserRole(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    role_name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='user', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<UserRole: {}>'.format(self.name)
```

**Routes for update**

```
@settings_blueprint.route('/user/<int:id>/edit', methods=['GET','POST', 'PATCH'])
def edit_user(id):
    found_user = User.query.get(id)
    form = UserForm(obj=found_user)
    if request.method == b"PATCH":
        found_user.user_role_id_user = request.form['user_role_opts']
        db.session.add(found_user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('User has been updated')
        return redirect(url_for('settings.index'))

    return render_template('settings/edit_user.html', id=id, found_user=found_user, form=form)
```

**edit_user.html page**

```
{% block app_content %}
    <h1>Edit User {{ found_user.username }}</h1>
    <div class="row">
        <form action="{{ url_for('settings.edit_user', id=found_user.id) }}?_method=PATCH" method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <p>
                {{ form.user_role_opts }}
            </p>
            <button>Edit User</button>
        </form>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

So in the database the user"Mark" has a role of "Senior manager"(id=2 in the database)
[pic database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7tif.png)

When I try and edit this user, the QuerySelectField automatically shows the role as "Director" (this is id 1 in the database)

[pic edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYPgx.png)

When i edit the user i need to see the pre-selected value of "Senior Manager" 
Any help would be greatly appreciated, i have gone around in circles with it.
Thanks